# Can you shorten this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

Is there a shorter phrase with this meaning:

> I invited him to my party verbally when I met him.

I thought perhaps the phrase *I invited him personally* meant this until I saw *personal* in written invitations, I'm still looking.

Comment: Yes. Why add _verbally_? Is anybody likely to think you sent him a text when you met him? If you mean _spontaneously_, say so; _verbally_ adds nothing to the sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler - He might have just handed him an invitation card

Comment: As far as the sentence construction goes, IMO, "I *verbally* invited him to my party when I met him" sounds better to me, with the adverb closer to the verb. Other than that, you could just have "I asked him to my party when I met him" is just as good

Comment: He might have thrown a pie in his face. The default mode for _invite_ in ftf communication is via speeh.

Comment: Look at this letter: http://www.fac.org.ar/1/externos/CVD%20Prevention%20Conference%20Invitation%20-%20Personal.pdf

Comment: "We would like to personally invite you to attend ...". I am sure that they did not meet all attenders to say them that they invite them. I think word "personally" in this phrase means "special for you".

Comment: I gave him a verbal invite when we met.

Comment: Incidentally, the phrase sounds natural and unambiguous the way it is. Why complicate matters when that's exactly what you wanted to say in the first place?

Comment: @JohnLawler *Verbally* does add to the sentence the sense that the message was so conveyed. Tradition requires in some cultures that even formal printed invitations be handed-in in person, esp., to A-Listers. And making an oral request to someone, on the other hand, signifies closeness, rather than formality -- I don't give out printed invites to close friends, I meet them and *tell* (rather than 'ask') them to "come over, buddies".

Comment: @Kris. I strongly disagree with you that the sentence above is natural.  As a native AmE speaker I would not use this phrasing and find it redundant. _I invited him to the party in person_ or _personally_ is what most would say, +/- _when I saw him_.  Also, _to meet_ has a secondary meaning _to make one's acquaintance for the first time_, so a native AmE speaker would not likely use this verb.  Quite grammatical, but not natural, in fact redundant, as stated.  No offense intended by this.

Comment: @Mike Did the OP or the question or the tags say anything about AmE? Why would we obsess with AmE alone? I know the OP is not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Kris. Who is obsessing about AmE?  I'm not obsessing about AmE, I'm merely qualifying my statement.  It is possible that native English speakers of other types perceive this to be a natural statement, though I doubt it.  The statement as above is very unnatural on a few points, though grammatical.

Comment: @AndreyEpifantsev. You are correct that in the invitation at the link, _personally_ refers to the recipient of the invite and not the originator of the invite.  However, in your sentence, depending in the context in which it is used, you have several options for a shorter sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I invited him *in person*.

Unless you used semaphores or slipped him a note, it would be implied that you asked him verbally.

By comparison, *invited him personally* means that you invited *him* specifically and not merely a group of people that may or may not have included him.  Or that *you* yourself invited him.

Comment: I should think "I invited him personally" means I did it myself as opposed to having had someone do it on my behalf.

Comment: @nxx Compare to a personal invitation . . .

Comment: I just read through previous comments. I presume there was a link in the question at some point that had the meaning you mention? So I read your answer without context; but it may still pay to point out that the meaning you state is not the only one!

Comment: @nxx Fair enough, I will add it.

Comment: I have read this discussions:
http://www.englishforums.com/English/InPersonAndPersonally/brnlwp/post.htm and 
http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1341584&langid=18

"in peson" means "face to face", so I think this answer is the best fit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:  "Can you shorten this?"  "Sentence" adds no information.  It is merely reflexive and can be dropped without impairing the message.

Answer (score 0):

"I invited him to the party organized by me."

Above sentence clearly shows you personally invited the person to a party which is organized by you i.e. to your party.

Comment: In your variant there is not information about how guest was invited. Did I send him a written invitation? Or did I ask him to come to my party when I met him?

Comment: Is it necessary mention that how guest was invited? Main focus is that the guest is invited to my party

Answer (score 0):

"Come to my party," I asked when I met him.